# Downloaded OCaml, get error "Bad CPU type in executable"

Tags: ocaml

So I'm running Mac OS X Yosemite 10.10.5. I need to use OCaml 3.08.3 to run [someone else's code](http://theinf1.informatik.uni-jena.de/ecc/) (the code won't run with the latest version of OCaml...), and I downloaded the .dmg file [here](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/distrib/ocaml-3.08/). The installation seemed to be fine, but whenever I run the command 'ocaml' in Terminal, I get

```
-bash: /usr/local/bin/ocaml: /usr/local/bin/ocamlrun: bad interpreter: Bad CPU type in executable
```

Anyone know what's up? Would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The version that you downloaded works only for Mac OS X 10.3 (Panther). It might work for some other versions, but it is not guaranteed. In MacOS, binaries compiled for one version, are often not compatible with other versions.

If you need a version of OCaml for which there is no binary distribution, you can always build it yourself, either manually (the hard way), or via the [OPAM](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html) system.

Alternative solutions would be using Docker or a virtual machine.

## Update

Also, the code that you're trying to compile doesn't really need exactly 3.08. It compiles perfectly fine on any version of a compiler, up to 4.04. The problem is that in a build system a fatal warning flag is turned on so that all warnings are translated to errors (a very bad practice of distributing software, I would like to say). The good news is that it can be easily fixed, just open `Makefile` in a text editor, and remove all occurrences of the following string `-warn-error A`.

Comment: Wow, your suggestion fixed everything! Thanks so much!

Comment: Perhaps not the best place to ask, but a small question (I've never used OCaml before): when I run the code (say "./ecc < example.graph"), it outputs each max clique in a separate line in Terminal. Is there any way I could get the output to be written to another file?

Comment: Just redirect it `./ecc < example.graph > result.cliques`